# Assign a different index to variable over the function

Tags: python, function, loops, abaqus

I am having trouble assigning different indexes to variables over a function in python. For example, if i have coordinates for points in 3D space and want to assign a name to a variable in a function, lets say "point_1", how do i do that?

Looking at this code:

```
side_1_point = (1.0,1.0,15.0)
side_1_face = boxPart.faces.findAt((side_1_point,))
side_1_region = regionToolset.Region(faces=(side_1_face))
 

side_2_point = (17.0,1.0,15.0)
side_2_face = boxPart.faces.findAt((side_2_point,))
side_2_region = regionToolset.Region(faces=(side_2_face))
 

side_3_point = (18.0,1.0,14.0)
side_3_face = boxPart.faces.findAt((side_3_point,))
side_3_region = regionToolset.Region(faces=(side_3_face))
```

How can i define a function as:

```
def assign_face(coord1,coord2,coord3,index)
    side_(index)_face = boxPart.faces.findAt((coord1,coord2,coord3,))
    return side_(index)_face
```

I am struggling to find the right syntax.
Thank you

Comment: You can't do this in python. Why don't you just put result in a dict?

Comment: even if you write such a method (using `exec` for example) it will not make a difference: the method will return the value not the name of a local variable. This question is not Abaqus related